# flake8 ignores config file and vimrc

Tags: flake8

I would like to extend the maximum number of characters allowed in a line from 80 to 120 in my python files (or simply ignore E501 in flake8 altogether). I have a flake8 config file `~/.config8/flake8`, which contains

```
[flake8]
ignore = E501
max-line-length = 120
```

However, both inside vim and in the terminal these lines do not seem to be picked up. Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863594/vim-flake8-ignoring-project-config-file) I also added the following line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--ignore=E501'
```

But still E501 is shown as before (all other commands in my `~/.vimrc` are correctly read by vim).

My `flake8 --version` returns `4.0.1 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.8.0, pyflakes: 2.4.0) CPython 3.7.10 on Linux` and `flake8 --version` in the terminal returns the following lines:

```
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess     61 INFO     Loading entry-points for "flake8.extension".
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    109 INFO     Loading entry-points for "flake8.report".
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    140 INFO     Loading plugin "C90" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    141 INFO     Loading plugin "F" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    153 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.ambiguous_identifier" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.bare_except" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.blank_lines" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.break_after_binary_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.break_before_binary_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.comparison_negative" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.comparison_to_singleton" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.comparison_type" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.compound_statements" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.continued_indentation" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.explicit_line_join" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.extraneous_whitespace" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.imports_on_separate_lines" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.indentation" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.maximum_doc_length" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.maximum_line_length" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.missing_whitespace" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.missing_whitespace_after_import_keyword" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.missing_whitespace_around_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.module_imports_on_top_of_file" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_async_await_keywords" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_backticks" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_has_key" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_invalid_escape_sequence" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_not_equal" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.python_3000_raise_comma" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.tabs_obsolete" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    157 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.tabs_or_spaces" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.trailing_blank_lines" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.trailing_whitespace" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_comma" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_keywords" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_named_parameter_equals" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_around_operator" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_before_comment" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pycodestyle.whitespace_before_parameters" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "default" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "pylint" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "quiet-filename" from entry-point.
flake8.plugins.manager    MainProcess    158 INFO     Loading plugin "quiet-nothing" from entry-point.
flake8.options.manager    MainProcess    158 WARNING  option --max-complexity: please update from optparse string `type=` to argparse callable `type=` -- this will be an error in the future
flake8.checker            MainProcess    165 INFO     Making checkers
flake8.checker            MainProcess    167 INFO     Checking 1 files
flake8.main.application   MainProcess    226 INFO     Finished running
flake8.main.application   MainProcess    226 INFO     Reporting errors
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [the flake8 4.x changelog](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/release-notes/4.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes):

> Due to constant confusion by users, user-level Flake8 configuration files are no longer supported. Files will not be searched for in the user’s home directory (e.g., ~/.flake8) nor in the XDG config directory (e.g., ~/.config/flake8)

you can of course use `--config ~/.config/flake8` if you need to explicitly restore the previous behaviour

---

disclaimer: I'm the current primary maintainer of flake8

Comment: Oh ok that's a pity. Is there an equivalent command that can be added in `.vimrc`?

Comment: presumably you'd do that the same way you'd use any other args (as you've found in your original post)